# How to get start date and end date from the given date column according to task completion in a day (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Here in dummy data, you can see there are two columns **Task_Completion** and **Time_stamp**.there is a java scheduler that runs whenever the task is finish, for example, scheduler run on **15-FEB-2016** 5 times and on **17-FEB** only time So I wanted a query that calculates the start_time and end_time from the given column **time_stamp**

```
Task_Completion                     Time_stamp
true                     15-FEB-16 11.37.56.013000000 AM
true                     15-FEB-16 11.42.55.593000000 AM
true                     15-FEB-16 11.47.48.970000000 AM
true                     15-FEB-16 12.21.57.587000000 PM
true                     15-FEB-16 12.26.55.767000000 PM 
true                     17-FEB-16 10.24.03.320000000 PM
true                     18-FEB-16 10.19.04.333000000 PM
```

So the output must be like

```
       start_time                                      end_time
15-FEB-16 11.37.56.013000000 AM          15-FEB-16 11.47.48.970000000 AM
15-FEB-16 12.21.57.587000000 PM          15-FEB-16 12.26.55.767000000 PM 
17-FEB-16 10.21.33.320000000 PM          17-FEB-16 10.26.33.320000000 PM
18-FEB-16 10.16.33.333000000 PM          18-FEB-16 10.21.33.333000000 PM
```

### There are two conditions

**condition 1.** if there is a **0-5min** gap in *time_stamp* for example on **15-Feb** then *start_time* will be *11.37.56.013000000* and *end_time* will be *11.47.48.970000000* but if there is not, then again check is there any schedule runs on that day like on **15-Feb** at 12.21.57.587000000(start_time) and 12.26.55.767000000(end_time)

**condition2.** if the schedule runs only once in a day then avg that **time_stamp** and add/sub **2.30 min** from that time (i.e.) no need to check again

**For Example**

*17-Feb 10.21.33.320000000(start_time)* and *10.26.33.320000000(end_time)* same as 18-Feb

So my logic was, to do a union of both condition1 and condition2 and this is I what end up with ...

```
--------------------condition2-------------------

select count(*), min(time_stamp) - interval '150' second start_date, max(time_stamp) + interval '150' second end_date
from serverstatus 
group by to_char(time_stamp,'dd-mon-yy')
having count(*)=1
UNION ALL

------------condition1 query--------------------------
```

**I need Condition1 Query**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT start_time - CASE num_grp_per_day
                      WHEN 1
                      THEN INTERVAL '150' SECOND
                      ELSE INTERVAL '0' SECOND
                    END AS start_time,
       end_time   + CASE num_grp_per_day
                      WHEN 1
                      THEN INTERVAL '150' SECOND
                      ELSE INTERVAL '0' SECOND
                    END AS end_time
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         MIN( time_stamp ) OVER ( PARTITION BY grp ) AS start_time,
         MAX( time_stamp ) OVER ( PARTITION BY grp ) AS end_time,
         COUNT( DISTINCT grp ) OVER ( PARTITION BY TRUNC( time_stamp ) ) AS num_grp_per_day
  FROM   (
    SELECT time_stamp,
           SUM( diff ) OVER ( ORDER BY time_stamp ) AS grp
    FROM   (
      SELECT time_stamp,
             CASE
               WHEN time_stamp - LAG( time_stamp ) OVER ( ORDER BY time_stamp )
                      <= INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
               THEN 0
               ELSE 1
             END AS diff
      FROM   your_table
    )
  )
)
ORDER BY start_time;
```

or, if you just want to expand all zero-width groups to a 5-minute interval (and not just when there is one per day) then:

```
SELECT MIN( time_stamp ) - CASE COUNT(*)
                             WHEN 1
                             THEN INTERVAL '150' SECOND
                             ELSE INTERVAL '0' SECOND
                           END AS start_time,
       MAX( time_stamp ) + CASE COUNT(*)
                             WHEN 1
                             THEN INTERVAL '150' SECOND
                             ELSE INTERVAL '0' SECOND
                           END AS end_time
FROM   (
  SELECT time_stamp,
         SUM( diff ) OVER ( ORDER BY time_stamp ) AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT time_stamp,
           CASE
             WHEN time_stamp - LAG( time_stamp ) OVER ( ORDER BY time_stamp )
                    <= INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
             THEN 0
             ELSE 1
           END AS diff
    FROM   your_table
  )
)
GROUP BY grp;
```

Comment: Pardon (I'm updating my query), but what if more than one schedule runs in a day with  time gap greater than 5.  then condition2 might fail. for **Example:** on 17-Feb-2016 schedule runs two times at 10:24:03 and 11:30:03  and on 18-Feb-2016 it runs 3 times  ... I understand your logic but unable to change it if this situation is occurring.

Comment: According to the logic in your question - condition 2 is only valid when the schedule runs once per day; if the schedule runs multiple times per day with more than a 5-minute separation then each group should be returned by the query and if there is only one entry then the start and end times will be identical - this complies with your condition 2. If it is not what you intended then you may need to clarify condition 2 to make your requirements more explicit.

Comment: Okay man thanks again ... Really your logics are unbeatable ☺ But there is a little update in my question, i ll post it tomorrow ... Hope you will answer it  :)

Comment: hi plz visit this link I have reposted my updated question
          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45479694/how-to-get-start-date-and-end-date-from-the-given-date-column-according-to-task