# How to get start date and end date from the given date column according to task completion in a day (oracle DB)

Tags: sql, oracle

Here in dummy data, you can see there are two columns Task_Completion and Time_stamp.there is a java scheduler that runs whenever the task is finish, for example, scheduler run on 15-FEB-2016 5 times and on 17-FEB only one time So I wanted a query that calculates the start_time and end_time from the given column time_stamp

```
Task_Completion                     Time_stamp
true                     15-FEB-16 11.37.56.013000000 AM
true                     15-FEB-16 11.42.55.593000000 AM
true                     15-FEB-16 11.47.48.970000000 AM
true                     15-FEB-16 12.21.57.587000000 PM
true                     15-FEB-16 12.26.55.767000000 PM 
true                     17-FEB-16 10.24.03.320000000 PM
true                     17-FEB-16 10.44.03.320000000 PM
true                     18-FEB-16 10.19.03.333000000 PM   
true                     18-FEB-16 10.23.03.333000000 PM
ture                     18-FEB-16 10.55.03.333000000 PM
```

So the output must be like

```
      start_time                                      end_time
15-FEB-16 11.37.56.013000000 AM          15-FEB-16 11.47.48.970000000 AM
15-FEB-16 12.21.57.587000000 PM          15-FEB-16 12.26.55.767000000 PM 
17-FEB-16 10.21.33.320000000 PM          17-FEB-16 10.26.33.320000000 PM
17-FEB-16 10.41.33.320000000 PM          17-FEB-16 10.46.33.320000000 PM
18-FEB-16 10.19.03.333000000 PM          18-FEB-16 10.23.03.333000000 PM
18-FEB-16 10.52.33.333000000 PM          18-FEB-16 10.57.33.333000000 PM
```

### There are conditions:

**If** there is a 0-5min gap in **time_stamp** for example on *15-Feb* then **start_time** will be *11.37.56.013000000* and **end_time** will be *11.47.48.970000000* but if there is not, then again check is there any schedule runs on that day like on **15-Feb** at *12.21.57.587000000(start_time)* and *12.26.55.767000000(end_time)*

**But if** a schedule runs with a time gap of more than 5min to next schedule on that date then query must return a **hard coded value** *for example* 
on **17-FEB-16** scheduler runs two times *10.24.03.320000000 PM* and *10.44.03.320000000 PM* so their gap is more than 5 mins then it must return output 2 times because time gap is more than 5 min. it that case add 2.30 min to start_time and 2.30 min to end_time (hardcoded) that is fix 
like *17-FEB-16 10.21.33.320000000 PM(start time)* , *17-FEB-16 10.26.33.320000000 PM(end_time)* **and**  17-FEB-16 10.41.33.320000000 PM(start time)   ,   17-FEB-16 10.46.33.320000000 PM(end_time) and this condition must apply to all dates.

**Similarly,** on 18th the schedule runs **3 times** so it will be count as 2 run i.e 10.19.03 to 10.23.03 and next 10.52.33 to 10.57.33 (2.30min-start_time and 2.30min+end_time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN( time_stamp ) - CASE COUNT(*)
                             WHEN 1
                             THEN INTERVAL '150' SECOND
                             ELSE INTERVAL '0' SECOND
                           END AS start_time,
       MAX( time_stamp ) + CASE COUNT(*)
                             WHEN 1
                             THEN INTERVAL '150' SECOND
                             ELSE INTERVAL '0' SECOND
                           END AS end_time
FROM   (
  SELECT time_stamp,
         SUM( diff ) OVER ( ORDER BY time_stamp ) AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT time_stamp,
           CASE
             WHEN time_stamp - LAG( time_stamp ) OVER ( ORDER BY time_stamp )
                    <= INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
             THEN 0
             ELSE 1
           END AS diff
    FROM   your_table
  )
)
GROUP BY grp;
```

Comment: Correct ... Thank you i just  run your query and it&#39;s working fine ...  Thank you MT0